# Prove that $C:\mathbb{R}_x^n \to T_xU$ defined as $v \to D_v$ is a bijection

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

> Prove that the map $C:\mathbb{R}_x^n \to T_xU$ defined as $C(v)=D_v$ is bijection. Where
>
> $D_v(f)=\frac{d}{dt} |_{t=0} f(x+tv)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x)v^i$
>
> for $f \in C^\infty (U)$.

> 1. Show that $C$ is a linear map.

I know how to prove that.

> 2. Show that $C$ is injective.

If for all $f\in C^\infty (U)$, $D_v(f)=0$ that means

$\frac{d}{dt} |_{t=0} f(x+tv)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x)v^i=0$

Since this is a derivative that equal zero, does that mean $f(x+tv)$ is constant?

> 3. Show that $C$ is onto. Hint: use Taylor's Theorem.

Not sure either.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, $f(x+tv)$ having derivative 0 at $t=0$ does not mean that $f$ is constant. For instance, take $f(t)=t^2$, then $f'(0)=0$ but $f$ is not constant. You need the derivative to vanish on the whole domain to conclude that $f$ is constant.

Anyways, let's turn to injectivity of this map. Suppose $D_v = 0$. Then *for every* $f \in C^\infty (U)$, $D_v(f) = 0$. So let's define $f(w) = \langle w - x, v\rangle$. The brackets here denote the usual inner product, and I'll leave checking smoothness up to you. Essentially, $f$ comes from projecting $w$ to the $v$ direction. We compute $f(x + tv) = \langle tv, v\rangle = t ||v||^2$. Hence, the derivative of this function at $t=0$ is $||v||^2$. As we assumed that $D_v = 0$, we have that $||v||^2 = D_v(f) = 0$. Hence, $v = 0$ so the kernel of this map is trivial.

For surjectivity, could you specify what exactly your definition of $T_x U$ is? The hint is correct that you have to apply Taylor's theorem, but the specifics of how this argument will be written will depend on this definition.

EDIT: Let's let $Y \in T_x U$. Let's also define by $p_i \in C^\infty (U)$, by $p_i(w) = \pi_i(w - x)$ where $\pi_i$ is projection onto the $i^{th}$ coordinate. We can therefore consider the values $\lambda_i = Y(p_i)$. Let $X = \sum \lambda_i D_{e_i}$, which is in the image of $C$. We claim $X = Y$. Indeed, take some $f \in C^\infty (U)$. By Taylor's theorem, we will write $f(w) = f(x) + \sum a_i p_i(w) + \sum (a_{ij} p_i p_j)(w)$. Here, the $a_i$ are constants and the $a_{ij}$ are smooth functions. Let $Z = X - Y$. Then $Z(f) = Z(f(x)) + \sum a_i Z(p_i) + \sum Z(a_{ij} p_i p_j)$. By the Leibniz rule, $Z(f(x)) = 0$. Furthermore, $Z(p_i) = X(p_i) - Y(p_i) = \lambda_i - Y(p_i) = 0$. Now, we are left to consider $Z(a_{ij} p_i p_j)$. Again, applying the Leibniz rule, this is $Z(a_{ij} p_i) p_j(x) + (a_{ij}p_i)(x) Z(p_j) = 0$. Hence, we have shown that $Z = 0$ so $X = Y$. We chose $X$ to be in the image of $C$, and $Y \in T_x U$ was arbitrary. Hence, $C$ is onto.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help! $T_x U$ is the tangent space to $U$ at $x\in U$.

Comment: Gladly! And I figured as much, but different texts will define the tangent space differently depending on how general they want to be and how advanced they assume the reader are. How does your test define the tangent space?

Comment: It is defined as a collection of linear maps from $C^\infty$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy Leibniz product.

Comment: I've edited in the solution for surjectivity @Dima.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help! Let me know if you have any questions.